# How can I autoload CodeIgniter library with parameters?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I need to autoload a CodeIgniter library with parameters. How?

Comment: kindly explain your question in a little detail what you wana to do

Comment: I want to autoload http://www.getfuelcms.com/user_guide/libraries/menu library with parameters. For example : $this->load->library('menu', array('active_class'=>'on', 'render_type' => 'collapsible'));

Answer (score 0):

Most CI system libraries have an “initialize” method. Passing an array to this method will override object properties, for example:

```
$this->load->library('email');

$params['smtp_port'] = 25;
$this->email->initialize($params);
```

Source: http://bit.ly/MS1yXK

Answer (score 0):

Create a config array and pass it with the loading of the library
Here is an example of facebook library...

```
$fb_config = array(
'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID_HERE',
'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET_HERE'
 );
$this->load->library('facebook', $fb_config);
```

Create a config file library.php in this case (facebook.php) in application/config

```
 <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
 $config['appId']  = 'YOUR_APP_ID_HERE';
 $config['secret'] = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET_HERE';
```

Load it in your controller and use it in your view accordingly